# viewForAnnotation returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Im trying to make a custom annotation. I made a custom annotation class, where i design the annotationview. Im trying to call the class in the viewForAnnotation in my Viewcontroller. When i run the app, it will show me the basic view. Here's the function. Let me know if you want to see the custom annotation class too.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


    let reuseIdentifier = "CustomAnnotation"


    if (annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomAnnotation)) {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as! CustomAnnotation!


        annotationView = CustomAnnotation(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        return annotationView
    }
        else {
            return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: for me it looks like you mix up the terms `annotation` and `annotationview`. you set up a custom `annotation` but try to use it as an `annotationview` (see the function signature: `MKAnnotation` != `MKAnnotationView`).

Comment: What do i have to fix?

Comment: how do you want your annotation to be presented on the mapview?

Comment: Just like the simple annotation pin. But when i tap the pin, there should be a large image, a title and a button. All that I've made i CustomAnnotation class as subviews.

Comment: so did you subclass `MKAnnotation` or did you subclass `MKAnnotationView`?

Comment: I subclassed MKAnnotationView, MKMapViewDelegate and CLLocationManagerDelegate

Answer (score 0):

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

```
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.animatesDrop = true
        pinView?.canShowCallout = false
        pinView?.draggable = true
              }
    else {
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Comment: And where does the custom annotation comes in?